# download xlsx from link and import into r

Tags: r, xls, xlsx, scrape

I know there are a number of posts on this topic and I usually am able to accomplish what I want just fine but I'm having trouble with this one particular link. It's likely related to the non-orthodox layout of the excel file. Here's my workflow:

```
library(rest)
url<-"http://irandataportal.syr.edu/wp-content/uploads/3.-economic-participation-and-unemployment-rates-for-populationa-aged-10-and-overa-by-ostan-province-1380-1384-2001-2005.xlsx"
unemp <- url %>%
  read.xls()
```

That produces an error `Error in getinfo.shape(fn) : Error opening SHP file`

The problem is not related to the scraping of the data. The problem arises in regards to importing the data into a usable format. For example, `read.xls("file.path/file.csv")` produces the same error.

Comment: Check out the help page `?download.file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the option `fileEncoding="latin1"` solved my problem.

```
url<-"http://irandataportal.syr.edu/wp-content/uploads/3.-economic-participation-and-unemployment-rates-for-populationa-aged-10-and-overa-by-ostan-province-1380-1384-2001-2005.xlsx"
unemp <- url %>%
   read.xls(fileEncoding="latin1")
```

Answer (score 0):

For example :

```
library(RCurl)
download.file(url, destfile = "./file.xlsx")
```

use your favorite reader then,

Comment: I know how to download files, what I'm saying is that this particular file I cannot import. Even if i have it saved on my hard using any good old "reader", it does not import. That's why I provided reproducible data!

Comment: df  = read.xlsx2("file.xlsx",1, startRow = 4,endRow=38 )
data = as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) { gsub("\\(2\\)", "", x)}))
str(data).  You still have to indicate type for columns  ....